# How to perform change detection using classified land cover map in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, change-detection

I have generated land cover maps of three different seasons using sentinel-2 data.
How can I generate a image that shows the changes of a land cover type between two classification results?

What I have:
1. classification result of summer 2019 with 3 classes in one band
2. classification result of winter 2019 with 3 classes in one band

What I hope to achieve:
1. generate an image that shows all 9 types of changes in classes from one image to the other

Comment: You need to provide more details of what you have and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var fromClassification = dummyClassification(2016)
var toClassification = dummyClassification(2019)
var classes = [1, 2, 3] // Class values in your classification. Doesn't have to be consecutive

var changes = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(
  classes.map(function (from, i) {
    return classes.map(function (to,  j) {
      var changeValue = classes.length * i + j + 1
      return fromClassification.eq(from)
      .and(toClassification.eq(to))
      .multiply(changeValue)
      .int8()
    })
  })
).flatten()).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a47987609f38a4e6f9607fa23cc5698e

Here, `changes` is an image where the pixel values mean the following:

1. From class 1 to class 1
2. From class 1 to class 2
3. From class 1 to class 3
4. From class 2 to class 1
5. From class 2 to class 2
6. From class 2 to class 3
7. From class 3 to class 1
8. From class 3 to class 2
9. From class 3 to class 3

Comment: Thank you, but what if I had like 5 classes in the classification and only secified class 2 to 4 in the code. What would happen to the changes of class 1 and 5?

Comment: Try and see what happens.

Comment: It seems the unspecified classes all returned 0.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable behavior.